# Space in foldername inside a FIND loop

Tags: terminal, command-line

I´m working on a script that need to read files inside a FIND loop.
Something like this :

```
DIRINI=/Volumes/dados/App\ Data/DATABASE.noindex/30000
for FILE  in `find "$DIRINI"  -type f ` ; do
stat $FILE
stat "$FILE"
stat '$FILE'
done
```

The problem is : when the foldername  has a space inside , i  have to put the var $DIRINI inside a ""  and this  make FIND works , but  the other commands inside the loop that use $DIRINI  does not work ,   they split  foldername in two use one half in each cicle.

Does someone have an idea of what can i do ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example with the shell performing word splitting. When you assign a variable with spaces the value must be quoted such as, `var="foo bar"`. When the variable `var` is expanded on the right side of a command the variable must be quoted or the shell splits the variable into two or more arguments.

When you use command substitution in a `for` loop, the command substitution is expanded as space delimited results. So,

```
for line in `find dir -type f`
```

expands into

```
for line in filename with spaces filename file name with spaces
```

each word becomes an argument instead of the actual filenames.

Solution 1: is to pipe the results of find into a while read loop:

```
find "$DIRINI"  -type f | while IFS= read -r line; do
    command "$line"
    command "$line"
done
```

Solution 2: use process substitution with a while read loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    command "$line"
    command "$line"
done < <(find "$DIRINI"  -type f)
```

Solution 3: just use find:

```
find "$DIRINI"  -type f -exec command {} \; -exec command {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Don‘t loop over results from find, there are too many things which can and will go wrong. Use

```
find "$DIRINI" -type f -exec stat {} \;
```

or

```
find "$DIRINI" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks Patrix , but this is only a example  , i have a whole sequence of  commands using this var $FILE inside the FIND loop.  I need the var to get the correct path of  each files and then use it!

Comment: @vilefort use `xargs` or `-exec` to call a shellscript with your code then.